# Using TNT4J, activity statistics are not coming properly

Tags: tnt4j

I want to log a activity which starts in the scope of a different class and ends in the scope of another class. Using TrackingLogger.getCurrentActivity() throws an exception as there is no activity in memory.Now if I try to store the activity in static HashMap in singleton Class and retrieve it in the other class, the snapshot of activity is showing confusing values. Here is what I am trying to do :

In first Class :

```
    TrackingLogger tracker = TrackingLogger.getInstance(this.getClass()) ;
    TrackingActivity activity = tracker.newActivity(); //
    activity.start();
    CacheUtil.addTrackingActivity("logger",activity); // Store it in static Hashmap in singleton class
```

In Second Class :

```
    TrackingLogger tracker = TrackingLogger.getInstance(this.getClass());
    TrackingActivity activity = CacheUtil.getTrackingActivity("logger");
    activity.stop();    
    tracker.tnt(activity);
```

this is the snapshot generated :

18:37:39,780 INFO  [Nastel TNT4J] {status: 'END' | time: '2014-07-30 13:07:39.778000 UTC' | sev: 'INFO' | type: 'ACTIVITY' | name: 'NOOP' | usec: '72827000' | wait.usec: '21000' | start.time: '2014-07-30 18:36:26.196000 IST' | end.time: '2014-07-30 18:37:39.023000 IST' | pid: '8092' | tid: '90' | id-count: '0' | snap-count: '6' | source: 'APPL=Nastel TNT4J#JVM=8092@FACH13140035#SERVER=FACH13140035#NETADDR=172.25.19.28#DATACENTER=default#GEOADDR=unknown' | track-id: '09d708c4-a6a9-4200-a70f-25c1da838c11'
    Snapshot(CPU@Java) {
        Count: 4
        TotalCpuUsec: 46800.3
        TotalCpuUserUsec: 46800.3
    }
    Snapshot(Thread@Java) {
        Count: 69
        DaemonCount: 46
        StartedCount: 85
        PeakCount: 69
        BlockedCount: 7
        WaitedCount: 0
        BlockedUsec: 21000
        WaitUsec: 0
    }
    Snapshot(Memory@Java) {
        MaxBytes: 532742144
        TotalBytes: 512499712
        FreeBytes: 216341712
        UsedBytes: 296158000
        Usage: 57
    }
    Snapshot(Copy@GarbageCollector) {
        Count: 477
        Time: 1940
        isValid: true
    }
    Snapshot(MarkSweepCompact@GarbageCollector) {
        Count: 13
        Time: 4652
        isValid: true
    }
    Snapshot(Activity@Java) {
        TotalCpuUsec: -1778411.4
        SlackUsec: 74584411
        WallUsec: -1757411.4
        BlockedCount: -24
        WaitedCount: -1
        BlockedUsec: 21000
        WaitUsec: 0
        OverheadUsec: 24290.215
    }}

Am I missing something?? Pls help ..

Answer (score 0):

TrackingLogger.getCurrentActivity() will only return a valid activity if executed within the same thread. The activity handle is stored in thread local. so you most likely calling TrackingLogger.getCurrentActivity() from a different thread and therefore get an exception.

I am not exactly clear where the confusing values are. Can you elaborate?